# 403 error from external request to magento 1.9 folders

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, api

I have magento connected with with a 3rd API, I receive a webhook notification response from the api but it cannot process any file and generate this 403 Forbidden error regarding some access rights. I've changed the magento folder to read and write access but the issue still the same.

```
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /magento1.9/app/code/local/Ns/Thorleif/Helper/Data.php
on this server.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the **.htaccess** in `\magento1.9\app` having the value **Deny from all**

Comment: But I see a new message in my admin dashboard "Your web server is configured incorrectly. As a result, configuration files with sensitive information are accessible from the outside. Please contact your hosting provider." . There is a way to hide it?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely running into a mod_security rule which is returning the 403. Contact your hosting provider and have them update the rule to allow the 3rd party modification to run.

Comment: I have it in localhost, and I use the ngrok to comunicate with webhooks API